# Need a good way to store Name value pairs

Tags: c#

I often run into a situation where I want to have a set of key/value pairs.  Here's a pseudo code idea:

```
DataSet MyRequestStatus
{
  Accepted = "ACC",
  Rejected = "REJ"
}
```

Usage:

```
InsertIntoTable(MyRequestStatus.Accepted.ToString())
```

I want to be able to use the friendly "MyRequestStatus.Accepted", but I want the ToString() to return the cryptic "ACC", NOT "Accepted".  Bonus points, implicit conversion rather than having to call ToString().

I haven't found an obvious way to achieve this with Enums.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Set the string value to be `"Accepted"`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you looking for a way to map the `MyRequestStatus.Accepted` enum value to the string `"ACC"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static class MyRequestStatus
{
    public const string Accepted = "ACC",
                        Rejected = "REJ";
}
```

Comment: +1: It was first when I saw your answer, that I understand what he actually asked for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public struct MyRequestStatus
{
    public static string Accepted = @"ACC";
    public static string Rejected = @"REJ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        d.Add("Accepted", "ACC");
        d.Add("Rejected", "REJ");

        string r = d["Rejected"];
    }
}
```

Now you have the whole dictionary API to work with.

Comment: You could use `StringDictionary` instead of `Dictionary<string, string>` - saves you some typing.

Comment: No, OP still has to type the word `"Rejected"` to get "REJ". I think OP wanted to avoid string literals altogether and stick with symbols. Also, I think OP wanted an actual type.

Comment: So Rejected instead of "Rejected"...got it

Answer (score 0):

Either use the class with constant strings as suggested by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155506/need-a-good-way-to-store-name-value-pairs/4155629#4155629), or if you want to keep the enum, set up a static Dictionary to contain the mappings:

```
private static Dictionary<MyRequestStatus, string> requestStatusToString = 
   new Dictionary<MyRequestStatus, string>()
{
   { MyRequestStatus.Accepted, "ACC" },
   { MyRequestStatus.Rejected, "REJ" }
};
```

Then you can do:

```
MyRequestStatus status = MyRequestStatus.Accepted;
string code = requestStatusToString[status];
```